# i want to know the cut off frequency on the 2 OPAMPS ... Do I take 6K resistor and 5K resistor for OPAMP#2

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter, passive-networks, cutoff-frequency

[image: How to calculate ripples RC frequency in case of these two OPAMPS with resistors]
I hope some one can check, I have a signal coming from a source and it goes in to 2 OPAMPS, and both has to be checked for cutoff frequencies...
I know 1/2*pi*RC is the formula but my question is how to calculate in case of resistor R1 and R3 and R2

[image]
How do I know what is Cutoff in this case? the knee is too broad to know...

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to factor-in that R1 and R3 adds resistance to R2 you'd calculate the parallel combination of R1 and R3 as 2.73 kohms. Then you would add it to R2 and get a total resistance of 3.73 kohms. This produces a cut-off (in conjunction with C1) of about 91 kHz.

This assumes that the input signal (V2) is a voltage source with low output impedance.

Comment: Why did you calculate R1 and R3 in parallel?

Comment: @FlávioAlegretti if you calculated the effective driving resistance at the node of R1 and R3 it is R1||R3. Think what happens when the input voltage is zero volts - what will be the impedance looking into the junction of R1 and R3... R1 will be in parallel with R3!

Comment: Sorry my ignorance, I don't really know much. Thinking when input is zero, it would be like doing thevenin wouldn't it? I get the impedance would be R1ll R3 when zero voltage is applied, but there is an active source in the circuit, how do I interpret it to be R1ll R3?

Comment: @FlávioAlegretti why don't you raise a new question about this rather than get half-answers in comments.

Comment: Hi Andy, Considering R3 and r1 are pull up and pull down resistors.Should I still calculate in the same way like u mentioned 

rt= (r1||r3) + r2 ; for the cutoff frequency? 

Also a question. If i have a simualtion result in which I get frquency on X axis and Voltage on Y axis... I get a knee type curve... I know cutoff is -3dB.... but the curve is too large e.g. 12 Mhz to 15 Mhz.... how wud I know cut-off frequenz in this case as there is no formula to know cut-off from Frequency vs. voltage graph!!!

pls help

Thanks

Comment: No, they are not pull-up and pull-down resistors - you have an AC signal source and my answer is still correct. I cannot comment on the 2nd part because I can't visualize the graph. Does this have anything to do with your actual question? If not, then why not raise a new question and embed a picture.